# Multible trait objects of the same instance wrapped by Arc<Mutex<_>>

Tags: rust, casting, mutex, automatic-ref-counting, traits

The goal is to have an object (`callback_handler`) implementing the traits `A`, `B` and `C` that can be passed to different functions that expect a trait object of type `A` or `B`, for instance.

This requires `callback_handler`, and the trait objects to be protected by the same `Mutex` (since, e.g., trait `A` expects `&mut self`). Furthermore, for this setup to work, this `Mutex` must be wrapped in an `Arc` or `Rc`:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait A {
    fn a(&mut self) {}
}
trait B {}
trait C: A + B {}

struct Foo {}

impl A for Foo {}
impl B for Foo {}
impl C for Foo {}

fn register_for_A(callback_handler: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn A>>>) {
    // Register for callbacks defined in `A`.
    // Store the passed handler somewhere.
}

fn register_for_B(callback_handler: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn B>>>) {
    // Register for callbacks defined in `B`.
    // Store the passed handler somewhere.
}

fn main() {
    let callback_handler = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(Foo{})));
    // Register for callbacks using different trait objects of the same "origin" object.
    // For this to be safe, all objects must be protected by the same ("shared") mutex.
    // !!! This will not work since there must be some steps to cast this to the right type. !!!
    register_for_A(Arc::clone(&callback_handler));
    register_for_B(Arc::clone(&callback_handler));

    // We can still use `callback_handler` to call methods on Foo ourself
}
```

Now, the question is, how can the origin object `callback_hanlder` of type `Arc<Mutex<Box<Foo>>>` be casted/converted to an `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn A>>>` and `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn B>>>`?
While I don't see a technical reason why this should not be possible, I don't know how to perform such a conversion and whether it is doable. While one solution would be using the `Any` trait, I was hoping that there is a solution that retains compile-time type safety for functions `register_for_A` and `register_for_B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by your double use of smart pointers `Box` + `Arc` you can simply cast an `Arc<Mutex<Foo>>` to an `Arc<Mutex<dyn A>>` using `as`, there is really no need to additionally `Box` it:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait A {
    fn a(&mut self) {}
}
trait B {}

struct Foo {}

impl A for Foo {}
impl B for Foo {}

fn register_for_A(callback_handler: Arc<Mutex<dyn A>>) {
    // Register for callbacks defined in `A`.
    // Store the passed handler somewhere.
}

fn register_for_B(callback_handler: Arc<Mutex<dyn B>>) {
    // Register for callbacks defined in `B`.
    // Store the passed handler somewhere.
}

fn main() {
    let callback_handler = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Foo{}));
    // Register for callbacks using different trait objects of the same "origin" object.
    // For this to be safe, all objects must be protected by the same ("shared") mutex.
    // !!! This will not work since there must be some steps to cast this to the right type. !!!
    register_for_A(Arc::clone(&callback_handler) as _);
    register_for_B(Arc::clone(&callback_handler) as _);

    // We can still use `callback_handler` to call methods on Foo ourself
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the reason for this not being possible with a `Box` in between?

Comment: You can cast one (smart) pointer to another type `Arc<Mutex<Foo>> as Arc<Mutex<dyn A>>` because you're diretly changing the pointer but for the example to work you would have to cast the inner `Box<Foo> as Box<dyn A>` which you can't cast because it's behind a pointer. You can't cast the pointee.